# How do I pass a parameter to a query script from a dropdown widget?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to pass a string value containing a "category" to a query script through a custom parameter:

[image: Query Script]

Then filter the datasource by that parameter, but when I reload the datasource on ValueEdit of the dropdown, it does not filter the table records. In addition, I have the script output a console message supposedly containing the "categoryParameter" but it shows up undefined.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your dropdown's value to the query parameter. Binding similar to this should work:

```js
@datasources.MyDatasource.query.parameters.categoryParameter
```

or in case the dropdown is already bound to the `MyDatasource` smth like this:

```js
@datasource.query.parameters.categoryParameter
```

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who might need it, I was stuck in this particular case.
The query is transmitted like a parameter in a function.

Do not initialize the variable "query" or you will overwrite it.
Use directly  :

```
var parameter = query.parameters.your_parameter
```

and not

```
var query = app.model.your_model.newQuery();
var parameter = query.parameters.your_parameter;
```